# Display Alert if Word not found on web page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way to display a pop-up alert if the customer did not select installation while checking out their product.  So on the checkout page, if it doesn't say the word "Install" on it - is it possible to display a nice alert popup that says something like "Are you sure you don't want installation?".

I found a script that I don't really know how to edit and I would like to only display the alert on the checkout page, and I don't have access to add code to just the checkout page, only the global script file.

Snippet of code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // If the body element of the page contains 'one hour turnaround' then trigger an alert
  if (document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('one hour turnaround') > -1) {
    alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order");
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option90049">
    <div style="font-size: 1.7em;border: 1px solid #e6db55; background-color: #FFFFE0; padding: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-wrench faa-wrench animated fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Would you like Professional Installation?</div>
  </label>
  <select name="option[90049]" id="input-option90049" class="form-control" data-toggle-option-select="true">
    <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
    <option value="179975">Yes - I need installation (+$95.00)</option>
    <option value="179976">No - I do not need installation</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    // If the body element of the page contains 'one hour turnaround' then trigger an alert
    if (document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('one hour turnaround') > -1) {
      alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order");
    }
  };
</script>
```

This is my HTML to the form on the product page to select if you would want installation or not...

```
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option90049">
    <div style="font-size: 1.7em;border: 1px solid #e6db55; background-color: #FFFFE0; padding: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-wrench faa-wrench animated fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Would you like Professional Installation?</div>
  </label>
  <select name="option[90049]" id="input-option90049" class="form-control" data-toggle-option-select="true">
    <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
    <option value="179975">Yes - I need installation (+$95.00)</option>
    <option value="179976">No - I do not need installation</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: "if the customer did not select installation while checking out their product" please provide the HTML since this appears as if it SHOULD be some sort of an input field

Comment: Done ^^ Added to OP

Comment: Depends on a word to find the result can be problamtic. If you have a valid HTML on that page, why not find by some unique value?

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer the question but given the actual use, I would suggest a verification - which can be triggered on load or select change.  Here is a very simplistic example.

I added a more standard way of doing a validation and triggered that when the page loads/script runs.

```js
function validateInstallation(event) {
  let installSelect = this;
  let optIndex = installSelect.selectedIndex
  let installSelectedValue = installSelect.options[optIndex].value;
  console.log("Value:", installSelectedValue, "Index:", optIndex);
  /* this could be in a validation message etc. also */
  if (optIndex == 0 || installSelectedValue == "") {
    console.log("Please select an installation option");
  } else {
    console.log("Selected:", installSelectedValue);
  }
}
let optionSelector = '#input-option90049';
let installOptionElem = document.querySelector(optionSelector);

// add a selectyionchange event listener and trigger that when we load
installOptionElem.addEventListener('change', validateInstallation);
const event = new Event('change');
installOptionElem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option90049">
    <div style="font-size: 1.7em;border: 1px solid #e6db55; background-color: #FFFFE0; padding: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-wrench faa-wrench animated fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Would you like Professional Installation?</div>
  </label>
  <select name="option[90049]" id="input-option90049" class="form-control" data-toggle-option-select="true">
    <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
    <option value="179975">Yes - I need installation (+$95.00)</option>
    <option value="179976">No - I do not need installation</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that code!  I used that on the product page.  But the problem I'm having is that if you're not on the product page, customers have a button that they can just add the product to the cart without seeing the installation option.  So On the checkout page I was wanting some sort of alert if the word Installation isn't found on the checkout page.

Comment: You should have IMHO an option (hidden/not visible) on the checkout page and populate that - I updated to show how to trigger that when it loads - but it could be triggered at any place desired.  Detecting text on a page for input validation/selection is likely NOT a best option here - again just my opinion/ but you could find some text inside a specific element also; you can determine your best option for text using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent as a guide